# IIS7 URL Rewrite for short urls

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I've been working on a small link length supressor site and can't seem to figure it out on IIS7. I'm used to working on isapi rewrite and mod_rewrite.

The following scenario is active:
Lets say I have test.com, thats the main domain. The domain should process all files normally. But when the `/.*` isn't a directory nor a file, it should send it to `redirect.asp?text=(.*)`.

This is what my web.config looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="YOURLS 1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^([0-9A-Za-z-]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="redirect.asp?test={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to have to do with a wrong version of the URL rewriter. I installed the latest 2.0 and it was fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Can't see much wrong with your rule, except maybe that you use `test` (with an 's') as the query string parameter in your `web.config` but in your text you say that it should be `text`. A typo or maybe that's the reason it's not working?

```
        <action type="Rewrite" url="redirect.asp?text={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
```

Comment: No, it ain't. Seemed to be a problem with the URL Rewriter. I had 1.5 installed and it didnt work. I've used the webinstaller to upgrade to 2.0 and it seemed to work just fine! Thanks for the help.